Iphone bottom bar color
When scrolled down on Iphone Safari browser a bottom bar becomes visible which has color according to body background. Any way I can recolor this?
Currently the problem I am having when I open fullscreen menu on my website which is different color than body background it will look off(for example if body background is yellow and fullscreen menu is pink then the fullscreen menu will have an yellow bottom bar below it)
Image for illustrative purposes

I've tried using  but this only recolors the top bar of Safari.
Any solutions or workarounds to this issue?
Cheers!
